# Can't understand scheme of creating API with Devise, RocketPants, Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, doorkeeper

I was developing website and decided to separate back-end(rails) and front-end(angularjs). All went good until I tried to implement authenticating over JSON. I've found tons of material on how to implement it with devise, or with doorkeeper, but I can't understand how to put it together. (API is implemented with RocketPants)

From what I've realized, from front-end I should send login and pass on init, getting back authtoken (step 1). Then on every call I should send authtoken with other data (step 2)

On step 1: Doorkeeper redirects_to sign_in page. Should I modify controller in way that it should come to controller, which would handle authentication (by using warden.authenticate!) ? And how does Doorkeeper know that I'm logged in since that moment? (for giving me authtoken)

On step 2: Authtokens are individual per user and per application, which uses API, right? So I should somehow specify, from which application request comes, shouldn't I? "

Note: Backend is going to be API only, so everything should be handled by JSON requests. But how I modify available applications then? One more custom controller over Doorkeeper?

Thanks in advance, I hope, I'm not the only one with such questions =)

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm thinking about the same thing..

Comment: @Brandon, yeah. I've covered some of experience in blog: http://morodeercoding.blogspot.ru/ . Feel free to contact me if anything seems unclear.